# can't download objects from google cloud storage using python

Tags: python, anaconda, google-cloud-storage

I tried to download objects from google cloud storage using python instead of using google cloud SDK. Here is my code:

```
#Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import Blob

# Downloads a blob from the bucket
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('sora_mue')
    blob = bucket.blob('01N3P*.ubx')
    blob.download_to_filename('C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Cloud')

    print ('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(source_blob_name,
                                             destination_file_name))
```

the problem is after I run it, there is nothing happened and no results. Did I do something wrong here? Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You have defined a function in python but have not invoked it. Calling the function should actually execute the code to pull the blob from your Google Cloud Storage bucket and copy it to your local destination directory.

Also, you're taking in arguments in your function but are not using them and instead using hard-coded values for blob name, GCS bucket name, destination path. Although this will work, it does defeat the purpose of defining a function in the first place.

### Working example

Here is a working example which uses the arguments in the function to make the call to GCS.

```
from google.cloud import storage

# Define a function to download the blob from GCS to local destination
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
  blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
  print ('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(source_blob_name, destination_file_name))

# Call the function to download blob '01N3P*.ubx' from GCS bucket
# 'sora_mue' to local destination path 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Cloud'
download_blob('sora_mue', '01N3P*.ubx', 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Cloud')
# Will print
# Blob 01N3P*.ubx downloaded to C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Cloud.
```

Comment: Thank you for  your explanation! I got it. Anyway, I just tried it, and the result is OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment. Actually, I already did gcloud auth, but I am still not sure which part that I do wrong.

Comment: Hi @Hasanah, it means that when you used the line storage_client = storage.Client(), the code couldn't figure out for itself what project you were trying to refer to.  If you specify your project on the cloud you should be OK.  Try:  storage_client = storage.Client(project='xxxxx') where xxxx is obviously your project name :)

Comment: In addition to what Paul already mentioned, the Cloud SDK Client libraries can automatically pick up the project name if you do not specify one, if and only if this information is available from the environment. `gcloud config list project` will tell you if you have a default project configured in gcloud. You can also set the project name through the following environment variables `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` or `GCLOUD_PROJECT`.